# Calculate Len of range of cell in VBA

Tags: vba

I am looking for a VBA code which will help me in calculating the no of characters in the range of cells.

If i use the excel option of LEN, it does gives me the no of characters in the particular cell.

Do we have any code which will give me the no of characters in a range of cells.

For ex; A1 = "Night" , B1 = "Day" C1 = "Noon"

The result should be 12 ( 5 + 3 + 4 )

Can any one help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom **UDF**, that using a loop will calculate the number of characters in a range, something like the code below:

```
Function SumLeninRange(Rng As Range) As Long

Dim C As Range

For Each C In Rng ' loop through all cells in Range
    SumLeninRange = SumLeninRange + Len(C.Value2)
Next C

End Function
```

And use the `Test Sub` code below:

```
Sub Test()

MsgBox "Num of Characters in Range is : " & SumLeninRange(Range("A1:C1"))

End Sub
```

Comment: I know it is OT but `SumLenin..` made my day, I come from eastern Europe...

Comment: @avb LOL , didn' even think about it :)

Comment: @SreeniVasan you'r welcome, this is the part you mark as "ANSWER"

Answer (score 0):

You do not need VBA to do this, just array formula
  `=SUM(LEN(A1:C1))`
type it and then press Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: Works perfect...just one question actually what Ctrl-Shift-Enter does

Comment: it creates array formula, see `{}` created outside fomula you wrote, you cannot add them manually

Comment: Thanks for the clarity..i was trying to add it manually and wondering why it didnt work :)